# Reply a comment not working using ancestry gem in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, ruby-on-rails-5.1, ancestry

I'm trying to create "**Reply a Comment System from Post**" using **Rails 5.1.6**

And I am using [Ancestry Gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/ancestry).

I followed [Railscasts #262](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I45gHY522Ms) as a guide.

I got a problem with this,

> When I submit a reply to each comment, it became a new comment. Not a
>   reply of comment.

I did what `railscast` did inside his form

`<% form_for @message do|f| %>` (in my case is @comment),

but i got this error **undefined method `comments_path' for**

So, i these codes :

```
<%= simple_form_for [@post, @comment]  do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :parent_id %>
  <%= f.text_area :body %>
<% end %>
```

and

```
<%= simple_form_for [@post, Comment.new]  do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :parent_id %>
  <%= f.text_area :body %>
<% end %>
```

and

```
<%= simple_form_for [:post, Comment.new]  do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :parent_id %>
  <%= f.text_area :body %>
<% end %>
```

But all these codes generated a new Comment, not a reply.

Here's my another codes :
**comments_controller**

```
def create
    @comment = @post.comments.new(comment_params)
    @comment.user = current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @comment, status: :created, location: @comment }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def new
    @comment = Comment.new(:parent_id => params[:parent_id])
  end
```

**Post model**

```
has_many :comments
```

**Comment model**

```
 has_ancestry
  belongs_to :post
```

**views/posts/show**

**views/comment/_comment**

```
<%= div_for(comment) do %>
  <%= comment.body %>
  <%= link_to "Reply", new_post_comment_path(:parent_id => comment, :post_id => @post) %>
<% end %>
```

**Routes**

```
resources :posts do
    resources :comments, only: [:destroy, :new, :create]
end
```

**Rake Routes**

```
post_comments POST     /:post_id/comments(.:format)            comments#create
        new_post_comment GET      /:post_id/comments/new(.:format)        comments#new
            post_comment DELETE   /:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)        comments#destroy
```

Is there anyone who can help me Please?

Comment: I'd need to see your schema or Reply model to follow. What is a `Reply`? I only see `Post` and `Comment` objects referenced in your example. Does a `Post` have_many `Comments` and are you referring to a Comment when you say "reply"? But really would need to see your controller and routes as well to determine why you're getting that error.

Comment: I mean reply is a comment of a comment system. When user is able to comment a comment of another user. I've edit my codes. Please take a look. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the answer..

I put :parent_id inside comment_params

```
  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:post_id, :body, :user_id, :parent_id)
  end
```